# Django import-export on Ubuntu 16.04 raises JSON error

Tags: django, ubuntu-16.04, django-import-export

I am trying to upload a *.xslx file from django app to the model. Everything worked great until I deployed the app on a linux VM (Ubuntu 16.04).

It raises the following error:
**the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'**

This is the code from my views.py:

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES["excel_file"])
            file =  request.FILES['excel_file']
            Import_Resource = resources.modelresource_factory(model=item)()
            dataset =  tablib.Dataset()
            if not file.name.endswith('.xlsx'):
                messages.error(request, 'This is not a excel file!')
            imported_data = dataset.load(file.read())
```

I tried to decode the dataset object (as utf-8), but then I receive the error that it cannot decode character a certain position - guess this is because of some special latin charcaters which are in the content of the file I am trying to import.
If I use latin-1 than it returns the following error: **`class 'KeyError'> 'p'`**.

This is the reviewed code which generates the above error:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES["excel_file"])
            file =  request.FILES['excel_file']
            Import_Resource = resources.modelresource_factory(model=item)()
            dataset =  tablib.Dataset()
            if not file.name.endswith('.xlsx'):
                messages.error(request, 'This is not a excel file!')
            imported_data = dataset.load(file.read().decode('latin-1'))
```

Do you guys have any ideas on how could this issue be tackled?

Comment: What is the full traceback of the error?

Comment: What is resources.modelresource_factory, what is tablib? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I installed Python 3.7, but am now trying to configure it on the VM as main version to be used. It seems that the default python on my Ubuntu VM is 2.7.3 (perhaps) this is the issue.

Comment: if seems that it was missing the file format type: imported_data = dataset.load(file.read(), format='xlsx') now it works! :)